# Qualtrics: Why is jQuery datepicker plugin not re-initializing when I return to the page it's on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, qualtrics

I can select the date from the calendar the first time I land on the page. But when I use the back button to come back to this page I can no longer select/change the date from the calendar. Should it not initialize on each page load?

Header:

```
    <input type="text" class="datePickerMonthYear" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" readonly="readonly">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()

{

jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" .InputText").hide();

jQuery(".datePickerMonthYear").datepicker({

   changeMonth: true,

   changeYear: true,

maxDate: 0,

minDate: new Date(1900, 0, 1),

dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",

yearRange: "1900:+00"

 });
```